# Voltage vs. Voltages

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage

Is 'voltages' the plural for voltage? When requesting for someone to check voltage more than once, would you state that you're documenting 'voltages'?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the voltage of different things, your checking the voltages.

If you double-check the same voltage, you're repeatedly checking the voltage.

If the voltage changes over time, or in different conditions, then you can use the singular:

> The voltage dropped steadily over two hours use.

But you can also use the plural, especially if the different conditions are well-defined:

> The maximum, mean and minimum voltages are within a narrow range.
>
> Different readings showed massively different voltages.

Comment: +1 is there more formal terminology to describe what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the voltage at the same place which is being checked at intervals, as implied, I think I would say that I am documenting 'voltage readings'. 'Voltages' might imply checking the voltage in two different places.

Answer (score 0):

If it is measured at the same place, I would use the singular. There's only one voltage there at a time. Measure the "battery voltage" at two temperatures. If there are two batteries, then you would measure the two voltages.

Once the measurements are made, you should use the plural to refer to the measurements. Measure the battery voltage at 0°C and at 100°C, then subtract the two voltages to determine the change in battery voltage. I hope that's not too confusing.

Perhaps someone can contribute a specific rule that covers this.